# Boost Serialization : Linker errors in XCode 5 project, generated from CMake (w/ minimal complete example)

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, xcode5, boost-serialization

In our main project, the build management is deferred to CMake. Everything was going fine for our different dependencies, including Boost::System, but we cannot get it to compile this minimal example for Boost::Serialization.

### CMake file

```
# Untested with previous versions, yet should work
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(SerialCmake)

# Boost dependency
set(BOOST_ROOT CACHE PATH "Path to Boost library")
find_package(Boost 1.55 COMPONENTS serialization system)

# Create the target
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

### CPP main file

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

class Serializable
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

public:
    Serializable(int a): a(a)
    {}

private:
    template <class Archive>
    inline void serialize (Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & a;
    }

    int a;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Serializable s1(1);

    // Save
    {
        std::ofstream ofs(argv[1]);
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << s1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Some more info

Our versions :

- XCode 5.0.2
- CMake 2.8-12
- Boost 1.55
- OSX 10.8

**EDIT:**

The two Boost libraries listed in the CMake are actually found (They are listed on CMake output as such).

Boost has been built first time with default parameters and a second time following the instructions in [this post](http://buddypanda.com/?p=39). The errors are the same with the two builds. (Actually, I think both builds are alright, since using the libraries in a non CMake project, by adding them to XCode as described in the same post, does work.)

### The problem

We are getting several (undefined symbols) linker errors :

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl::save(std::string
>   const&)", referenced from:
>         void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, std::string const&) in
>   main.o
>   "boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl::text_oarchive_impl(std::ostream&,
>   unsigned int)", referenced from:
>         boost::archive::text_oarchive::text_oarchive(std::ostream&, unsigned int) in main.o
>   "boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive::~basic_text_oprimitive()",
>   referenced from:
>         boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl::~text_oarchive_impl()
>   in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

**Any direction ?** (As you can see, we are asking to link the application against both Boost::Serialization and Boost::System).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check that all libraries is actually found by `find_package` command. Easiest way
to do it is to add [REQUIRED](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3afind_package) sub-option:

```
find_package(Boost 1.55 REQUIRED system serialization)
```

Works fine for me. Xcode 5.0.2, Boost 1.55, CMake 2.8.12.1, OS X 10.9. I'm using custom boost build (not system) with static libraries.

#### PS

IMHO there is no need to clear `BOOST_ROOT` variable:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT CACHE PATH "Path to Boost library")
```

If boost is already found (by other parent project) you will do find-work twice, if project use custom boost location, you will rewrite it.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to look into this. I forgot to mention the libraries were actually found (I still added REQUIRED to the command).
The only difference I see is in OSX version (we use 10.8), but I do not think that could be it. I am really puzzled at this one !

Comment: @AdN I'm pretty sure you have `make` command installed, have you try use simple [UnixMakefiles](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#gen:UnixMakefiles) generator (which is cmake-default on Mac). What is verbose output? (`set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)`). I think it's some trivial (: Check that your boost include dir points to library dir location. Check that your boost library is linked to same standard c++ library (`stdlibc++` or `libc++`)

Comment: Sir, a HUGE thank you ! **It was a standard library issue** (seems that my compiler's default is GNU libstdc++, even if the default compiler is Clang). Switching the project to explicitly using libc++ made it link correctly. It is not usual to mention that here, but be aware that you had a major impact on my working week : thanks again.

Comment: @AdN I'm glad it helps (: Yep, it's pretty annoying problem, and it becomes more annoying if you're using custom library location. I'm experimenting with cmake toolchain files to fix this issues. You can found my [github](https://github.com/ruslo/polly) project.

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, I had a similar problem after adding back in serialization to one of my targets, and it was just that cmake wasn't picking up the change in CMakeLists.txt so had to remove the cache:

I merely added the "serialization" to:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem date_time serialization)
```

and had this error:

```
  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

      boost_serialization
```

so solved with:

```
rm CMakeCache.txt
cmake ./
```